# Probability of error in fusion majority bit rule

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A binary bit is transmitted into n channels, each with its own probability of error (p1,p2,..pn). At the receiver end, n bits are received from n channels, with a total combination of 2^n possibilities.

At receiver, there is a decision making body which operates on a majority rule. For example for 5 channels, if the received bits (32 combinations) have 3 or more "1/0", it will decide that bit to be used.

I wanted to obtain P(error) in terms of (p1,p2....pn) for such a system. How can I obtain a generic mathematical expression for such system?

Comment: It will be a mess in general, particularly if $n$ is even.  There may be some decent approximations for large $n$ in some cases

Comment: By mess, you mean it have numerous PI notations?